# Search By Number and Get the image using ABAddressBook

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, abaddressbook

I wish to search in the iphone AddressBook through my app using the number as the key and then retrieve the image associated to that contact and display it on the UIImageView.

I tried using ABAddressBook framework but was clueless to proceed.

Can anyone please suggest me the solutions or any alternative path that I can follow. Any code snippet would also be of great help!!

Any form of help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The AB framework can be a real pain at times.  But it breaks down to a series of pretty simple operations.  First, you have to create an ABAddressBook instance:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

Then you'll want to make a copy of the array of all people in the address book, and step through them looking for the data you want:

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
CFIndex numPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
for (int i=0; i < numPeople; i++) {
```

Inside your loop, you'll probably want to get a reference to the individual person:

```
ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
```

Then you want to compare the number you have (lets call that `inNumber`) to every phone number associated with that particular person.  To do that, you first need a list of all the person's phone numbers:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phonelist = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Then, of course, you'll need to have an inner loop that loops over each of the individual person's phone numbers:

```
CFIndex numPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);
for (int j=0; j < numPhones; j++) {
```

Since the phone numbers have both numbers and labels associated with them, you'll need to extract the actual phone number string as an NSString:

```
CFTypeRef ABphone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneList, j);
NSString *personPhone = (NSString *)ABphone;
CFRelease(ABphone);
```

Now you can finally compare numbers!  Do so with the standard NSString comparison methods, but remember that you need to worry about formatting, etc.

Once you find the person who has a phone number matching `inNumber`, you'll want the extract that person's image into a `UIImage`:

```
    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
    CFRelease(imageData);
```

When it comes time to exit, you'll need to clean up memory.  A general rule of thumb for the AB framework is that anything with `Get` in the function name you don't need to release, and anything with `Copy` or `Create`, you do need to release.  So, in this case you'll need to `CFRelease()` `phonelist`, `allPeople`, and `addressbook`, but not `numPeople`, `person`, or `numPhones`.

Comment: Mr.Jeff,it looks like you have a pretty good command over ABAddressBook framework and key features.Can you please take a minute or 2 in having a glimpse at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138946/access-contact-image-from-address-book-based-on-name. Expecting to receive a response soon,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)fetchAddressBook:(NSString *)searchnumber
{
    ABAddressBookRef UsersAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    //contains details for all the contacts
    CFArrayRef ContactInfoArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(UsersAddressBook);

    //get the total number of count of the users contact
    CFIndex numberofPeople = CFArrayGetCount(ContactInfoArray);

    //iterate through each record and add the value in the array
    for (int i =0; i<numberofPeople; i++) {

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ContactInfoArray, i);

        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        //Get phone no. from contacts
        ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        UIImage *iimage;
        NSString* phone;
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); j++) {
            iimage=nil;
            phone=nil;
            phone = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, j);



            //if number matches
            if([phone isEqualToString:searchnumber])
            {
                NSLog(@"equlas%@",searchnumber);

            //if person has image store it
            if (ABPersonHasImageData(ref)) {

                CFDataRef imageData=ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(ref, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
                iimage = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)imageData];

            }else{
                //default image
                iimage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];

            }

         //set image and name
                userimage.image=iimage;
                lblname.text=firstName;

                return;
            }


        }

    }
}
```