# Get a Contact Picture ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I am trying to figure out how to add persons **last name** and **first name** in this code below in order to get their contact image from my phone:

```
if(ABPersonHasImageData(aABRecordRef))
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(aABRecordRef)];
   cell.imageView.image = image;
} else {
   UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"User.jpg"];
   cell.imageView.image=image1;
}
```

I could also be missing code here so please do fill in the areas where it is needed. I just cant figure out how to add the **first,last** name to the code above so i know when i have reached that contact to extract the image for it.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the FirstName and LastName , you can use :

```
NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(aABRecordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(aABRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```

Here it shows how to [Search By Number and Get the image using ABAddressBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115977/search-by-number-and-get-the-image-using-abaddressbook).

But you want to search By FirstName and LastName. So According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001024-103495) , you should use [-recordsMatchingSearchElement:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABAddressBook/recordsMatchingSearchElement:) method for Multiple Arguments.

Once you get the matched Data , you can extract the image using below code :

```
CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(aABRecordRef);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
CFRelease(imageData);
```

Hope you get something useful from this.

Comment: You are welcome...StealthRT !! Even I got something from this Research.

Comment: @Bhavin can i get that local image url from the contact... please tell if it possible

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CFStringRef firstName, lastName; // can cast this to NSString *

firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(aABRecordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(aABRecordRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, how do i tell it what to look for? would i just do **if (firstName == "the first name here") {}**?

Comment: NEVER compare strings like that. use -isEqualToString