# How to select multiple contacts from phone addressbook and record in the app?

Tags: iphone

I want to select multiple contacts from the iPhone address book and save selected contacts in my app. then I have to retrieve record of that selected contacts.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have an real question?

Comment: your not asking a question here. what is the issue your having ? do you have any code to show us ? have you tried / researched / googled anything before asking for help ?

Comment: i found from google with example also :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747844/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-on-ios

Comment: Check My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14260304/1603072 , if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

check this demo

1)   [multicontactsselector](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multicontactsselector)

2)   [knmultiitemselector](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/knmultiitemselector)

3) [tkcontactsmultipicker](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tkcontactsmultipicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```