# Getting user's name and profile picture via address book

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to get the profile picture and name of the user via the Address Book API (iOS 6)?  This would be the equivalent of asking for "me" data from the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: I think this answer may help you:
[Search By Number and Get the image using ABAddressBook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115977/search-by-number-and-get-the-image-using-abaddressbook)

Comment: Yep I'm set on these interactions with the API.  I'm looking for a way to get the user's own data.